# What is the opposite of "Reference Data"?

Tags: database, terminology, static-data

I'm looking for a term that means "non-reference" data i.e. any data in a database that strictly ISN'T reference data.

```
      Master Data
           /\
          /  \
         /    \
        /      \
       /        \
      /          \
Reference Data   ???
```

Is there such a term? Would have thought there must be but can't seem to find one - constructive suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Don't know why this had been voted down, it generated some interesting responses and I think this is a useful, pragmatic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a while ago I asked this but my own personal favoured answer would be **Operational Data**, which could be interpreted to mean data that can be modified by business operations.

It is also possible to take this a bit further and broadly divide into three (although there may be some crossover between these):-

- **Reference Data**: Fixed for the whole duration of an application.
- **Operational Data**: Directly managed by the application during normal business operations.
- **Volatile Data**: Can be changed by external processes without being directly controlled by the application. (This may or may not be a subset of Operational Data).

Comment: What would an example of Transient Data be?

Comment: @DaveInCaz One example is an asset being polled periodically and sending its telemetry data to the application, which then persists its status information.

Comment: `Silo`-ed data as well which would be like `Transient` but not be so *day-to-day*; its accessibility too.

Comment: Also I might consider instead of `Transient` to use `Transactional` which suggests its more dynamic in nature than a staid `Operational` type of data.

Comment: Coming back to this 5 years later I think I may have been confusing my Java keywords and actually meant *volatile* rather than *transient* - in the sense that such data could change unexpectedly (from the point of view of the application) due to something external. Have modified the answer accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

Transaction Data is another possibility. Again using "Transaction" in a broad sense. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_data) Transaction Data requires a time value.

Comment: Hmmm again this is close but no cigar I think. The Wikipedia article says "Transaction data always has a time dimension". So it sounds like this is a subset of "non-reference" data since time might not be relevant. E.g. coming back to the example above, the number of milligrams of each ingredient in a cigarette is "non-reference" data without a time element.

Answer (score 1):

Customer Data perhaps? Using "Customer" in a broad sense. So it might cover an internal list of Departments as well as Purchases.

Comment: Good effort and nice to get a reply after winning a "Tumbleweed" badge for this one. But I can't help feeling a better term is needed as the customer probably thinks they own their reference data as well. E.g. for a cigarette company the reference data might include lists of ingredients and the "non-reference" data might include sales of each product. Could be wrong but I'd think of both these as Customer Data.

Answer (score 0):

Well my answer is proference data or inference data as opposite to Reference Data. Profer with an O not an E. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profer

Where I focus on using the stem / root -fer. For refer means to carry back to.

Proference Data, as in produced (or product) data. Profer means to carry forth to or carry over to or carry out to. And I don’t mean proffer (which is like legal offer)

Inferenced Data, is probably the only other option as it means to carry out to in logical steps.

The link is where I ask a related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/584642/440001

Comment: Btw Wikipedia use the word Referent